# update MutableList inside Map

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to create a data structure in Kotlin with key/value pairs where the key is an Integer and the value is a mutable list of Integers. Something like (pseudocode):

```
1: 10, 20, 30
2: 50, 30, 25
3: 5
...
```

I'm not sure what the best data structure to use for this would be, but I'm trying to do this with a map:

```
var map = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Int>>()
```

I have a couple of questions about this:

Does the map need to be mutable? The keys and values are dynamic, but there will also be an `Int` key that matches to a `MutableList` value.

Is this the most appropriate data structure for doing something like this?

Do I need to first check to see that the key exists or can I just start setting values at keys, like:

```
var id = 2
// assuming the map has already has [2]: 10, 3, this would mutate it to [2]: 10, 3, 5
map[id].add(5)
```

Comment: Just as a note, unless you want to reassign the `map` variable (i.e. `map = ...`) after initialization, it should be `val` and not `var`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not sure what the best data structure to use for this would be, but I'm trying to do this with a map:
>
> ```
> var map = mutableMapOf<Int, MutableList<Int>>()
> ```

Good choice.

> Does the map need to be mutable?

Yes, unless **all** of the keys (not necessarily values - you can have empty `MutableList`s as defaults) are known during the *creation* of your map.

> Is this the most appropriate data structure for doing something like this?

It's a little subjective, but given the information you provided - yes - in my opinion.

> Do I need to first check to see that the key exists or can I just start setting values at keys, like:
>
> ```
> var id = 2
> // assuming the map has already has [2]: 10, 3, this would mutate it to [2]: 10, 3, 5
> map[id].add(5)
> ```

If the `id` already exists inside the map, you can do `map[id]!!.add(5)` (note the `!!`, because `Map`s operator `[]` return an optional (`?`)). You can either ensure the compiler that it exists (via `!!`) or use `?.` check for it first.

---

As an alternative to separate checks for `null` entries, you can use `getOrPut` method:

```
map.getOrPut(id, ::mutableListOf).add(5)
```

Thanks to **@Tenfour04** for this addition.

Comment: You can use `map.getOrPut(id, ::mutableListOf).add(5)` to avoid having to separately check for a preexisting entry.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you for that, I completely forgot about such convenient combination. Added it to my answer.